# How to update homescreen widgets from flutter code

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I've made the app in flutter and I've added the android widget written in Kotlin.

They are completely separate and they update their data separately from the same source.

The only thing that connects them is sharedpreferences where the key value pair are set via flutter app.

Is there a way to trigger homescreen widget update (reinit) via flutter code, on some button click or something?

Comment: Interesting question, also looking for an answer